# Why is my linked list in C failing?

Tags: c, algorithm

I was going to write a simple SDL app so I thought I should implement a simple linked list that I can extend later. Now after some struggling with it I decided to ask for help here.

I know the linked list, I read about it. I saw couple implementations, not so hard, easy to grasp. So I thought I should be able to implement one myself.  I am guessing that I am severely overlooking something here. :(

First this code does not compile well, segmentation fault. Second I do not think that it is going to produce what I want if I can overcome the basic errors I am doing with the pointers unfortunately.

Can you please show me my mistakes in my code? Where am I doing wrong?

Here is a liveworkspace link for editing
http://liveworkspace.org/code/1qu1RN$1

Here is the error I get on Cygwin gcc

```
temp [v 0] -> 0.460241 0.000000 0.050356
temp [v 1] -> 0.072079 0.153807 0.864573
temp [v 2] -> 0.683917 0.709301 0.080479
temp [v 3] -> 0.295755 0.264795 0.894696
address of ptemp @ 1629101750

[v 0] -> linked vertex is  7731159828445146316135105405324534341657178000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 578395405356271.125000 1310047834864691498231654014730274851713450000.000000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NEWline printf("\n")

typedef struct position {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} position;

struct datalist {
    position v;
    struct datalist  *pnext;

};
typedef struct datalist datalist;

void initializeList (datalist *head);
void addList_II (datalist *head , double data[3] );

void initializeList (datalist *head){
    position pv= {0,0,0};
    head = (datalist *) malloc ( sizeof (head) );
        if (head == NULL){ printf("cannot allocate memory");  exit(1); }
    head->v=pv;
    head->pnext=NULL;
}

void addList_II ( datalist *head , double data[3] ) {

    datalist *adddata;
    adddata = (datalist *)malloc ( sizeof (datalist) );
        if (adddata == NULL) { printf("cannot allocate memory for insertion data"); exit(1); }
    adddata->v.x = data[0];
    adddata->v.y = data[1];
    adddata->v.z = data[2];

    adddata->pnext = head->pnext;
    head=adddata;
}

int main() {

    datalist *ptemp;
    datalist temp;
    int i,c; //counters
    datalist *head;

    initializeList(head);

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        double t[3];
        srand ( time ( NULL )*i+234 );
            temp.v.x = ((double ) rand()  )/ RAND_MAX;
        srand ( time ( NULL )*i*546 );
            temp.v.y = ((double ) rand()  )/ RAND_MAX;
        srand ( time ( NULL )*i*567+345 );
            temp.v.z = ((double ) rand()  )/ RAND_MAX;
        t[0] = temp.v.x; t[1] = temp.v.y; t[2] = temp.v.z;

        printf ( "temp [v %d] -> %F %F %F \n",i, temp.v.x, temp.v.y, temp.v.z );
        addList_II (head, t );
    }

    c=0;
    ptemp=head;
    while (ptemp!=NULL) {
        printf("[v %d] -> linked vertex is  %F %F %F \n", c, ptemp->v.x,ptemp->v.y, ptemp->v.z);
        ptemp=ptemp->pnext;

    }
}
```

Comment: There a few occurrences of where the sizeof a pointer is being malloc()d instead of the sizeof of an object.

Comment: yes, in your initialization. make sure you fix this and do sizeof(datalist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `addList_II` you are setting the wrong pointer. You are taking your new node and pointing its next pointer to the head's next pointer, which is null.

```
   void addList_II ( datalist *head , double data[3] ) {
        datalist *adddata;
        adddata = (datalist *)malloc ( sizeof (datalist) );
            if (adddata == NULL) { printf("cannot allocate memory for insertion data"); exit(1); }
        adddata->v.x = data[0];
        adddata->v.y = data[1];
        adddata->v.z = data[2];

        //    adddata->pnext = head->pnext; //not THIS
        adddata->pnext = head;        //DO THIS
        head=adddata;
    }
```

Additionally your pointers were going out of scope in your function calls. what you need to do is pass in ** variables. This means your passing in a pointer to a pointer, which points to your block of memory. You modify the original pointer by derefrencing your local *, and upon return you are good.

If you need more explanation, just ask, but heres the solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NEWline printf("\n")

typedef struct position {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} position;

struct datalist {
    position v;
    struct datalist  *pnext;

};
typedef struct datalist datalist;

void initializeList (datalist **head);
void addList_II (datalist **head , double data[3] );

void initializeList (datalist **head){
    position pv= {0,0,0};
    *head = (datalist *) malloc ( sizeof (datalist) );
        if (head == NULL){ printf("cannot allocate memory");  exit(1); }
    (*head)->v=pv;
    (*head)->pnext=NULL;
}

void addList_II ( datalist **head , double data[3] ) {
    datalist *adddata;
    adddata = (datalist *)malloc ( sizeof (datalist) );
        if (adddata == NULL) { printf("cannot allocate memory for insertion data"); exit(1); }
    adddata->v.x = data[0];
    adddata->v.y = data[1];
    adddata->v.z = data[2];

    adddata->pnext = *head;        //DO THIS
    *head=adddata;
}

int main() {

    datalist *ptemp;
    datalist temp;
    int i,c; //counters
    datalist *head;

    initializeList(&head);


    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        double t[3];
        srand ( time ( NULL )*i+234 );
            temp.v.x = ((double ) rand()  )/ RAND_MAX;
        srand ( time ( NULL )*i*546 );
            temp.v.y = ((double ) rand()  )/ RAND_MAX;
        srand ( time ( NULL )*i*567+345 );
            temp.v.z = ((double ) rand()  )/ RAND_MAX;
        t[0] = temp.v.x; t[1] = temp.v.y; t[2] = temp.v.z;

        printf ( "temp [v %d] -> %F %F %F \n",i, temp.v.x, temp.v.y, temp.v.z );
        addList_II (&head, t );
    }

    ptemp=head;

    while (ptemp!=NULL) {
       NEWline; 
        printf("[v ] -> linked vertex is  %F %F %F \n", ptemp->v.x,ptemp->v.y, ptemp->v.z);
        ptemp=ptemp->pnext;

    }
}
```

Comment: just for clarity, you get through 1 iteration of your while loop because you set head = adddata. therefore, the only node in memory you have a pointer to is contained in the head node. All others are floating off in space somewhere.

Comment: 75inchpianist I thought that that would be problem in my previous versions so I created " datalist *start;    then set start=head; then ptemp=start; Is that what you are talking about? That did not help me then but probably I was having other issues in parallel;

Comment: your main issue is in your addList_II function, not in your while loop. The use of ptemp in your loop is not the issue, the issue is that you are trying to assign ptemp = null when you do ptemp = ptemp->pnext. Since your addList_II function is setting ptemp->pnext to null, you get your seg fault.

Comment: Thank you all for great help. I modified the code and so far I am not able to create a successfull linked list with all the great help here :( Here is the link to the modified code http://liveworkspace.org/code/3HS0pc$0

Comment: see my answer edit, your pointers were going out of scope in your function calls.

Comment: @75inchpianist, thank you that is great. Naturally my next question will be about making a more concise version of this. I mean  based on the way I was trying to do to, would there be any other way of doing this in C (maybe without declaring global variables). I guess I am wondering if it is possible to write one that does not use pointer to pointers.

Comment: +1 for the answer. It's amazing how many times people get the exact same thing wrong in one form or the other.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code it seems to me that in function `addList_II` you should substitute the previous to last line with

```
adddata->pnext = head;
```

instead of:
    adddata->pnext = head->pnext;
Otherwise you always lose one element.
Then you can simply set `head=NULL` instead of initializing the list.